# Automated Flutter Notifications with Firebase Cloud Functions, Messaging, and Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having trouble with understanding how to implement automated notifications with Flutter. Within my app, when a user creates/updates an alarm, the changes are stored on Firebase Firestore. Each user has multiple alarms, with each alarm having multiple fields (alarm information). What i'm trying to figure out is how to implement cloud function(s) to work with Firebase Cloud Messaging and Firestore to successfully send a notification when an alarm time is met. For example, a user can set an alarm for 8:30 am, and that's when I want the notification to be sent to the user (if the alarm is active). Any suggestions?